# How can I draw attention and get feedback to my answer for improvement

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I thought I had a good answer like [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220972/reduce-feature-levels/220999#220999). But the answer got no up vote or comment and seems no one care.

How can I get attention to more users , with more feedback? Even down vote with a reason, like [Zach here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23486/can-we-be-nicer-to-downvoters)?

Comment: This question is good--but the example is not quite apt.  First, your post has been up for only six hours! Second, that question is unclear: the purpose of the grouping of the factors has not been disclosed. It is a borderline thread that probably ought to be closed as unclear until the OP explains the situation better. The lesson to learn is that jumping ahead and answering a poorly formulated question is rarely a good response.  (There are always exceptions: if you are confident about your interpretation, *and explain that interpretation clearly*, then such an answer can be helpful.)

Comment: @whuber Thanks. I am still tying to find what is CV. So you think CV should be a slowly updated more formal tutorial blog instead of a quick QA platform? Most questions are not that good, and good questions are already have good answers. How can I contribute?

Comment: See http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1390 .

Comment: So, may be I should stop to go though the unanswered questions to answer them? Many of them are not so good. I tried my best to answer them but seems no one cares. If I spend sufficient time to one answer, I can make it much better.

Comment: I agree that answering old unanswered questions is usually not very rewarding: few people notice and even fewer people vote. The OP is usually not around to accept any answers, either.  But [some of us do it anyway,](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/badges/64/revival) because there are some interesting questions lurking on this site. In the process, I find a lot of bad old questions, so I vote to close them (or sometimes try to improve them).

Comment: How can we keep the retention of the user? If one user spend a lot of time and no one cares. He/she may leave. Also do you know in most cases, how long does a person will be "active" in CV? Sorry for a off topic chat.

Comment: There are various ways to explore the data to assess activity, but one easy way to gauge how many are currently active is to look at the ["reputation leagues"](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/19/week/stats). Anyone with a modest reputation or higher who is currently gaining substantial reputation is likely active and has been around a long time. That's several hundred people.

Comment: thank you very much to spend time with me to chat. I do plan to spend more time and write better question and answers to CV. But back to my original question, can we encourage user (especially high reputation ones) to give more feedback?

Comment: hxd -- I can't have voted or commented on answers you post when I am asleep, until after I am awake and had time to look through the posts -- let answers be up for a couple of days before you conclude they get no response.  Additionally if you answer a question I don't feel competent to answer, I also might not vote on an answer I am unsure about the value of.  [I have quite a few answers nobody has voted up/down, nor commented on/accepted - maybe 70 or so, not counting the ones I deleted (which are mostly my earliest posts - it took me time to learn how to give answers people would upvote).]

Comment: [This query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/110381/users-with-most-badges-of-a-certain-name) (and then search for `Revival`) can be used to help identify people who spend lots of time answering old unanswered questions. One way of drawing attention to others is to vote for their posts. About all you can do for your own posts is make them as good as you can.

Comment: Unfortunately in many cases you can't... Editing title and re-tagging question if it has wrong tags and misleading title may draw some more attention to the Q and your A. You can answer when there is many users online (http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/3107/35989). However in many cases upvotes are a little bit random and number of upvotes do not have to say anything about quality of your answer (plainly wrong answers get few upvotes from time to time).